# Mysql: Negative balance query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called customer_wallet with id as primary key, balance(contains both -ve & +ve values), date(transaction date).

Now some customers have privilege that they can do transactions in even if they have no balance. We get total Balance of a customer by doing (SUM(balance) where customer_id=xxx).

I want to find out the date when customers balance comes to -ve(like 3 days ago or 5 days ago) only if current balance is in negative.

Below is sample data set:

```
balance_id  customer_id balance description date    
1           1           100     Recharge    1-Dec-17    
2           1           100     Recharge    1-Dec-17    
3           2           20      Recharge    1-Dec-17    
4           2           -10     Shopping    2-Dec-17    
5           1           -150    Shopping    2-Dec-17    
6           1           -100    Shopping    3-Dec-17    
7           1           50      Recharge    4-Dec-17
8           1           -200    Shopping    5-Dec-07
9           1           300     Recharge    6-Dec-17
10          1           -100    Shopping    6-Dec-17
11          1           -250    Shopping    7-Dec-17
12          1           -20     Shopping    8-Dec-17
```

As from above dataset `cutomer_id=1` have balance in -ve    with -300 and date when balance comes to negative is 7-Dec-17

I just want to fetch this details for a list of customers within single query.

Comment: well - what have you tried? and what dmbs are you using? mysql or sql-server - theyre kindof different...

Comment: If a Customer's Balance switches between negative and positive several times during the period, do you wish to know the first time that it went negative, the most recent time, or all of the times?  Also, is this for all records or just those that occur in a specified period (such as December 2017)?  If the latter, then what sort of period are you using?

Comment: Also, there is no `-300` value in the above list, which most recently becomes negative on `6-Dec-17`.  Please correct your question.

Comment: My advice would be: don't store the balance, just compute it when needed based on previous transactions. Just store how much each transaction added or removed from the account. Then SUM the rows to get the current balance. To get the balance at a specific date/time, simply restrict the SUM query to transactions on or before that date/time.